# Different articles for similar nouns "humanity" and "environment"

Tags: articles

Why is it correct to write "the environment", while "humanity" usually goes with zero article?
I rationalised to myself using "the" article with "environment" by the fact that we have only one environment, but it turns out not to be the case. At least this rule of thumb does not apply to "humanity".

Comment: quite the opposite: there are many environments that exist, and "the environment" means different things in different contexts.

Comment: "environment" is countable while "humanity" is not. That's part if not all of the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of environments. You can speak about the environment in your local area. A single room can be an environment. And, having specified what kind of environment you are speaking about, you could use the definite article with any of them - for example, "*the environment in my classroom is conducive to learning*".

Whenever you use a definite article, your audience is expected to know the unique thing or person you are talking about. And when we say 'the environment' without any prior specification it is generally understood to mean the ecosystem or ecology of the entire planet.

By contrast, there is only one 'humanity' (when used to mean humans as an entire race) which is why you can use it with zero article. The only time you would use the word with an article is if you were speaking about an individual's humanity, eg "*the humanity of [x]*".